# How to run Mike Bostock's D3 examples?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I've been trying to run Mike Bostock's [See-Through Globe](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6747043) example, but the references to his json files are incorrect if you try to reproduce it locally.

The issue comes from this line of code:

```
d3.json("/mbostock/raw/4090846/world-110m.json", function(error, topo) {
      var land = topojson.feature(topo, topo.objects.land),
          grid = graticule();
});
```

I've followed this example:
[d3: us states in topojson format filesize is way too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941975/d3-us-states-in-topojson-format-filesize-is-way-too-large)

and tried to change the url to these variations to better reference those files for an external user;

```
"https://raw.github.com/mbostock/topojson/master/examples/world-110m.json"
"https://render.github.com/mbostock/topojson/master/examples/world-110m.json"
"http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4090846/world-110m.json"
```

but I'm never allowed access. Any idea on how to correctly reference the json file?

I've tried some if his other examples as well, and have run into the same issue every time. Has anyone else had any success reproducing the examples?

#### Issue reproduced in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/agconti/wBfLd/

[Link to gallery example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6747043)

[Link to github gist](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/6746848)

Comment: You can't access the remote json files because of same origin policy. And you won't be able to retrieve a JSON object using the `file:` protocol. Unless you want to perform surgery on the code by embedding the JSON directly, you're going to have to run a local server.

Comment: I've tired to download the files and refrence them locally without success. Do I need to run a simple server as well? Is there no way to use `jsonp`? Also, how can I find the example json files. they're not listed on the gists or his site. I just happened to find the github link through another SO post.

Comment: @StephenThomas Your question helped me figure it out if you post it as an answer, and add `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888 &` from the root dir, I'll accept.

Comment: Updated fiddle, loading the json data via rawgit.com: http://jsfiddle.net/wBfLd/3/

Comment: Just be careful with using the examples in your code - they're GPLed, and I for one can't figure out what that means in terms of Javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't access the remote json files because of same origin policy. And you won't be able to retrieve a JSON object using the file: protocol. Unless you want to perform surgery on the code by embedding the JSON directly, you're going to have to run a local server.

An easy way to run a local web server is execute:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888 &
```

from the "root" directory of your site and then access it via `http://localhost:8888`

Comment: I know this is about a year later, but what does creating your own server achieve to bypass the same-origin policy?

Comment: FYI in Python 3, the equivalent command is `python -m http.server 8888 &`

Answer (score 5):

You can access the data directly here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4090846/world-110m.json

To make it work, you'll need to create a new variable in your script and assign the json to it directly.

Code from the fiddle you provided:

```
var topo = // Paste data from provided link here. It will be one big object literal.

var width = 960,
    height = 960,
    speed = -1e-2,
    start = Date.now();

var sphere = {type: "Sphere"};

var projection = d3.geo.orthographic()
    .scale(width / 2.1)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
    .precision(.5);

var graticule = d3.geo.graticule();

var canvas = d3.select("body").append("canvas")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection)
    .context(context);

// d3.json("https://render.github.com/mbostock/topojson/master/examples/world-110m.json", function(error, topo) {
  var land = topojson.feature(topo, topo.objects.land), // topo var is now provided by pasted-in data instead of fetched json.
      grid = graticule();

  d3.timer(function() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

    projection.rotate([speed * (Date.now() - start), -15]).clipAngle(90);

    context.beginPath();
    path(sphere);
    context.lineWidth = 3;
    context.strokeStyle = "#000";
    context.stroke();
    context.fillStyle = "#fff";
    context.fill();

    projection.clipAngle(180);

    context.beginPath();
    path(land);
    context.fillStyle = "#dadac4";
    context.fill();

    context.beginPath();
    path(grid);
    context.lineWidth = .5;
    context.strokeStyle = "rgba(119,119,119,.5)";
    context.stroke();

    projection.clipAngle(90);

    context.beginPath();
    path(land);
    context.fillStyle = "#737368";
    context.fill();
    context.lineWidth = .5;
    context.strokeStyle = "#000";
    context.stroke();
  });
// });

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");
```

I would have modified the fiddle directly, but the json data file is large enough that jsfiddle chokes when I try to paste it in.

Hope this helps.