# In an example for a worldmap for d3v4 world_countries.json can't be found

Tags: d3.js

When running the examaple found over here: http://bl.ocks.org/micahstubbs/8e15870eb432a21f0bc4d3d527b2d14f

I get the error that world_countries.json can't be found:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)   http://localhost:8000/world_countries.json

world_countries.json is used in this piece of code:

```
queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "world_countries.json")
    .defer(d3.tsv, "world_population.tsv")
    .await(ready);
```

I figured that world_countries.json might come from topojson, this is the way I load in the existing libraries

```
    <script src="http://d3js.org/queue.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/graphs/d3-tip.js"></script>
    <script src="js/graphs/map.js"></script>
```

I was really hoping someone could help me out here!

Comment: I'm not sure how bl.ocks works and why its not showing up there, but you def. need that json file to draw the countries; you can find it here - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jdamiani27/Data-Visualization-and-D3/master/lesson4/world_countries.json

Comment: a similar answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/21032766/1732222

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the terminal:

`curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jdamiani27/Data-Visualization-and-D3/master/lesson4/world_countries.json`

this will download `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jdamiani27/Data-Visualization-and-D3/master/lesson4/world_countries.json` to your current working directory.

or just visit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jdamiani27/Data-Visualization-and-D3/master/lesson4/world_countries.json in the browser, select-all, copy, paste into your favorite text editor and save as `world_countries.json`, in the same directory as the other files from the d3 example that you are working with.

good luck!

Comment: On second look it was álmost the solution, the json you linked is not the one used in the example but the one that sparta94 send was the correct one! https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jdamiani27/Data-Visualization-and-D3/master/lesson4/world_countries.json

Comment: edited the answer with the correct link. thanks for noticing!